# Javascript push function

Tags: javascript, angular, dictionary

I want to create simple social media app.I'am working now on part with groups.But I cant filter only groups where some user is member.The code is following

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { GroupsService } from '../groups.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-groups',
  templateUrl: './groups.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./groups.component.scss']
})
export class GroupsComponent implements OnInit {
  uid = localStorage.getItem('uid')
  groups: Array<any>;
  mygroups: Array<any>;
  sgroups;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private _groups: GroupsService) {
   }


  ngOnInit() {
    this._groups.getGroups().subscribe((data) => {
      this.groups = data;
    })
    this.loadGroups()
  }
  search(e) {
    this.sgroups = this.groups.find(gr => gr.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) > -1)
  }
  loadGroups() {
    this.groups.map(gr => {
     this._groups.getGroupMembers(gr.id).subscribe((data: any) => {
         data.map(mem => {
           if(mem.uid == this.uid) {
            this.mygroups.push(gr); //here is the problem
           }
         })
     })

    })
  }
  scrollnav() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }
}
```

Every **help** is welcomed.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's `this.uid`?

Comment: I do not see where `mygroups` is ever initialized to an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in initialization. intialize mygroups like

```
mygroups: any[] = [];
```

instead of

```
 mygroups: Array<any>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forkJoin` to fire all of the calls at once and get an array with all the results:

```js
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';

...

const requests = this.groups.map(gr => this._groups.getGroupMembers(gr.id));

forkJoin(requests).subscribe((res) => this.mygroups = res);
```